# cannot be cast to java.lang.String Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, adonis.js

Sorry, this is my second question but i Really not found solve to this problem...

i use react native with expo and my backend its adonisjs. I try send JWT token to adonis(Auth provider) in axios.get request but i have this error :

[image]

my code is:

```js
      let data = null
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('scute-user-token')
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + value;
      if (value == null){
        this.props.navigation.navigate('App')
      } else {
        await axios.get('/account/me')
        .then(response => {
          data = response.data.data
        })
        let tokenpersonal = await AsyncStorage.getItem('scute-personal-data')
        if(tokenpersonal !== null){
          await AsyncStorage.removeItem('scute-personal-data')
        }
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('scute-personal-data', data)
        this.props.navigation.navigate('App')
      }
```

the solved why i found its use JSON.stringify() but the problem in this why the "Auth provider" of adonis dont accept the string JWT tokem in this case my question its this:

¿is there any way of solved this error? o ¿How do I alter the auth provider on adonisjs for use toJSON in the parameter of jwt received?

Thx 4 the answers

Answer (score 0):

Finally i Solved this. Result why Asyncstorage dont sabe a Json Object and i need save in string and in the instant i need transform string tojson